# ini_set(max_execution_time) for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

Why can't I load my page in my inventorycontroller?

I use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30)` and higher, but this seems to have no effect at all, I still receive an error. The first 3 module are running fine, but the last part is not.

I use laravel 5.1 and Laragon

```
public function getIndex()
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);

    $in_transit = CartonMasterFile::getCount('I');
    $received = CartonMasterFile::getCount('R');
    $pending = CartonMasterFile::getCount('P');
    $transferred = CartonMasterFile::getCount('T');
    $dispatched = CartonMasterFile::getCount('D');
    $total_boxes = CartonMasterFile::getTotalBoxes();
    $total_quantity = CartonMasterFile::getTotalQuantity();

    return;
}
```

I don't know why  `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30 or 300);` has still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) is not able to be modified by `ini_set()` if `safe_mode` is enabled

Laragon should disable this by default, but in case you enable it somewhere else, you should check this setting first

Or, your program is not dead because of executing time, but from some other limitations like `memory_limit`, you should check your error log for sure

Comment: Hi this is php.ini. is this correct? and when i see error in Devtools(f12) no pop up on preview or response. Only timing,it say the connection start(time only 7secs) the process is too early so it cant load thats why i think. but i wonder where is the problem.                                                                                                                         
my php.ini is this correct
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 60
max_input_nesting_level = 64
 max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 512M

Comment: Run a separate php program with a single line: `<php? phpinfo(); ?>` in it, would be easier for you to determine what's the final setting in your runtime.

Comment: And, it's hard to say is your php.ini correct or not since we can't sure how much resource (memory, execute time) will your program need. And also, in your source code it will only response the browser after all the jobs finished, it's correct that you can only see `connection start` in Devtools before it finish